# Why are my dynamic text fields sometimes populating and sometimes not?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game where the user will view his/her high score and score at the end of the game. This is the code when the player sees the results page:

```
function showresults():void
{
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("alltimeHighScore");
if (so.data.score == undefined || score > so.data.score)
{
    endscreen_mc.scoreR_txt.text = String(score);
    endscreen_mc.highscore_txt.text = String(score);
}
if (score < so.data.score)
{
    endscreen_mc.scoreR_txt.text = String(score);
    endscreen_mc.highscore_txt.text = String(so.data.score);
}
so.data.score = score;
so.flush();
}
```

It sometimes populates and sometimes does not. I have another level with a similar code as well:

```
function showresultsA():void
{
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("alltimeHighScore");
if (so.data.scoreA == undefined || scoreA > so.data.scoreA)
{
    endscreenA_mc.Ascore_txt.text = String(scoreA);
    endscreenA_mc.highscoreA_txt.text = String(scoreA);
}
if (scoreA < so.data.scoreA)
{
    endscreenA_mc.Ascore_txt.text = String(scoreA);
    endscreenA_mc.highscoreA_txt.text = String(so.data.scoreA);
}
so.data.scoreA = scoreA;
so.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that i notice is that their is no condition statement for when so.data.score equals score.

```
if(so.data.score==score){

}
```

If this is true when the code runs then obviously the text wont be updated. Other than that, since your code example is short, I can't offer another reason why it does not show up sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think, that **Xiler** is right: you do not take into account cases, when score is equal to the chached high score.
2. The second issue is that you might populate the 'score' field outside of the 'if' condition - you should display it always.
3. You're overwriting a highscore everytime, even if it's actually is not larger, than current highscore.

So, please, try to change your function showresults() like this:

```
function showresults():void
{
   // display current score
   endscreen_mc.scoreR_txt.text = String(score);

   // calculate, display and save (if necessary) a new highscore
   var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("alltimeHighScore");
   if (!so.data.score || score > so.data.score)
   {
       endscreen_mc.highscore_txt.text = String(score);
       so.data.score = score;
       so.flush();
   }
   else
   {
       endscreen_mc.highscore_txt.text = String(so.data.score);
   }
}
```